# How can I change the parameter name in the request body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this model 'LoginModel'.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Pssd { get; set; }
}
```

I use this class on the controller tho get the values from the body like this.

```
public object CheckLogin([FromBody]LoginModel logModel){}
```

So to be able to get the values I have to put this in the request.

```
{
  "UserName": "username",
  "Pssd": "password"
}
```

I want the parameter 'Pssd' to be 'Password' while keeping Pssd as its method name. I've already tried to use these attributes but it still doesn't work. When I replace Pssd to Password inside the request body,  its value becomes null.

```
    [JsonProperty("Password")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Password")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
```

I also tried removing [FromBody] but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `[BindProperty(Name ="password")]` ?

or try with simple letter 'password'  `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]`

Working sample.

```
[Route("test")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginDto x)
{
    return Ok(x);
}

public class LoginDto
{

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Pssd { get; set; }
}
```

request

```
{
  "username": "test",
  "password": "test"
}

Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: I have. But still doesn't work. The body only recognizes 'Pssd'

Comment: I tried and it works for me, I update the answer with sample source code

Comment: Its not working for me :( Is the value placed in 'password', test or null for you?

Comment: Its "test", This one works fine. Check your api has some overrides